# Chrome persistently shows cached pages even when clearing cache

Tags: caching

When I clear cache in Chrome I'm still seeing old data.  Something very strange is happening.

I need a fix that will fix this for everyone not just me.  The client reports clearing cache constantly and their clients are also seeing files which no longer exist on the server.  The database has changed and the files are looking at different tables.

Is there a way to avoid the site being cached at all?

The problem is that this site is a jobs board and showing old jobs is causing them major problems, and people are unable to apply for new jobs even though they are online.

I have tried setting .htaccess to the following.

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Can anyone think of any other reasons the cache would not be updating even when clearing cache and cookies?  If the PHP files are different I would expect this cannot be browser cache, but the host says Cloudflare is not active and there is no other server cache.

Comment: I am facing the exactly similar issue with Chrome browser. Any help in this regards will be appreciated.

Comment: @KasimHusaini I've written my answer, but I doubt it will help you sorry.  Chrome does have quite strict caching.  Have you asked a question?  If so put it here and I will try to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue caused by using Google Optimize.  Clearing cookies cleared the Google Optimize cookie which was a bit of a red herring.  So for others reading, on a dynamic site, don't use the Google Optimize page editor as it doesn't use the dynamic content any more.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comments. Can you please elaborate on how I can avoid using Google Optimize? I haven't used Google Optimize page editor ever.

Comment: If you haven't used it then it is not the issue.  I had used it therefore, that was my particular issues.